# Do we need the “language” tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need the "[language](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)" tag? I see it's pretty much used as a synonym for the tag [nlp](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so. There actually isn't that much overlap.

- 38 tagged with [language](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), NOT [nlp](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) ([link](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language+-nlp))
- 14 tagged with [nlp](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp), NOT [language](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) ([link](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp+-language))
- 6 tagged with [nlp](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) AND [language](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) ([link](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp+language))

Of course, there could be plenty of mis-tagging in the above examples.